# SQL query relation between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables and I can use MS access version to join them together 
It worked both in Access and SQL. However, can someone rewrite join in SQL version 
Many thanks.

```
(This is MS Access version)
SELECT [something]
FROM TaxonomyCrosswalk tc RIGHT JOIN (TargetTerm tt RIGHT JOIN (SearchTermShort st RIGHT JOIN RTMMobileAppDataFINAL rm ON (st.ActionID = rm.ActionID)
AND (st.DeviceID = rm.DeviceID)) ON (tt.ActionID = rm.ActionID)
AND (tt.DeviceID = rm.DeviceID)) ON tc.Service = st.SearchTermShort;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write this using `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `RIGHT JOIN`s.  This is usually what is intended:

```
SELECT [something]
FROM RTMMobileAppDataFINAL rm LEFT JOIN
     TargetTerm tt
     ON tt.DeviceID = rm.DeviceID AND 
        tt.ActionID = rm.ActionID LEFT JOIN
     SearchTermShort st
     ON st.ActionID = rm.ActionID AND
        st.DeviceID = rm.DeviceID LEFT JOIN
     TaxonomyCrosswalk tc 
     ON tc.Service = st.SearchTermShort;
```

There are some subtle differences in chains of `LEFT JOIN`s versus `RIGHT JOIN` when intermediate tables are missing matches that are in the outer tables.  However, this structure is usually what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it with `LEFT JOIN`s & do table swapping  :

```
SELECT [something]
FROM RTMMobileAppDataFINAL rm LEFT JOIN
     SearchTermShort st
     ON (st.ActionID = rm.ActionID) AND (st.DeviceID = rm.DeviceID) LEFT JOIN
     TargetTerm tt
     ON (tt.ActionID = rm.ActionID) AND (tt.DeviceID = rm.DeviceID) LEFT JOIN
     TaxonomyCrosswalk tc
     ON tc.Service = st.SearchTermShort;
```